# How to get Google plus share in popup like Twitter?

Tags: google-plus, google-plus-one

The Google+ icon automatically shares the page on HOVER, and doesn't require a click like the others. Is there anything that can be done about this, to require a click like the others [fb,twitter] and to load in a popup as happens with the Twitter share icons?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The JavaScript `window.open` method will open a new window. You can combine this technique with the [share link](https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/share/#sharelink) to accomplish your goal. Here's an example of this technique lifted from the [official docs](https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/share/#sharelink). Just substitute your target url for `http://example.com`.

```
<a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=http://example.com"
  onclick="javascript:window.open('http://example.com','',
  'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=600,width=600');
  return false;">
  <img src="https://www.gstatic.com/images/icons/gplus-64.png" 
    alt="Share on Google+"/>
</a>
```